# background image inline with text

Tags: html, css

I have an image 200px x 100px which acts as a background image to a link. 
On hovering, the bg image changes.

[image]

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EnsFK/

As you can see from the image, the text is not aligned with the image and appears at the bottom. Is there a way to align the text so it is in the middle (Aligned with the small dot?) I've tried vertical-align and 
line-height but to no avail.

```
.current-location {
    line-height: 24px;
    background-size: 48px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.current-location span {
    background: url(images/mobile/current-location.gif) left top no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 48px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.current-location:hover span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: -24px 0px;
    background-size: 48px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: You have changed background position on .current-location:hover span which is causing that.

Comment: Wrap your text in the fiddle in a div and try what i suggested i my answer. You should wrap the text in something if you like to move it.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using an *empty span* in your markup, you could use `pseudo elements`.

Something like this:

```
.current-location:before {
   content: '';
   /* image here */
   margin-right: x px; /* however much you need */
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EnsFK/2/)**

### Markup:

```
<a href="#" class="current-location">Use this location</a>
```

### CSS

```
.current-location {
       line-height: 24px;
       background-size: 48px 24px;
       height: 24px;
       width: 24px;
       text-decoration: none;
       position: relative;
     }
     .current-location:before {
         content: '';
          background: url(http://i39.tinypic.com/2lk5lci.png) left top no-repeat;
          display: inline-block;
          background-position: 0px 0px;
          background-size: 48px 24px;
          height: 24px;
          width: 24px;
          margin-right: 10px;
          vertical-align: middle;
      }
     .current-location:hover:before {
          background-position: -24px 0px;         
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the `line-height` of the text to fit the image's location, or play with `background-position` property for the image's position to fit it to the text.

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnsFK/)** - also removed some of the unnecessary code.

```css
.current-location {
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 26px;
    display:inline-block;   
}

.current-location span {
    background: url(http://i39.tinypic.com/2lk5lci.png) left top no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 48px 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.current-location:hover span {
    background-position: -24px 0px;
}
```

**Note:** this is usually done without the `<span>` element using background on the anchor itself. However you method will work just as fine with the new CSS..

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this css snippet for vertical centering

```
#text{
   position:absolute; 
   top:50%; 
   height:240px; 
   margin-top:-120px; /* negative half of the height */
}
#container {
   position: relative; 
   height: 400px; 
}

<div id="container">
 <div id="text"><span>Text.....</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ChrisMoutray if you center a div and but the background image on the div. I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is aligned properly look at your image instead

```
background: url(images/mobile/current-location.gif) left top no-repeat;
```

If you want it to be center aligned you should consider doing...

```
background: url(images/mobile/current-location.gif) center center no-repeat;
```

Also give the true width and height of the image for this method to work.

```
display: inline-block;
```

has problems with ie6 you will need to use:

```
display:inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

try and stay away from vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

How about a version with no images and no extra markup? http://jsfiddle.net/6aaZX/

For this HTML:

```
<a href="#">Use this location</a>
```

This CSS:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 4em;
    line-height: 2;
}

a:before {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
     border-radius: 50%;
    background: #81B995;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0.7em;
    height: 0.7em;
    border: 0.4em solid #B7E2C8;
    margin-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: -0.3em;
}
```

It requires support for border-radius, but that's it - nothing fancy otherwise. If you did need to use an image, you could apply it to the :before pseudo element, as suggested by Danield